# Disable tabpage and enable when button is click in c#

Tags: c#, tabcontrol, tabpage

I have the this code to disable tab page:

```
private void tabControl_Selecting(object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.TabPage == tabPage)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

and i want to enable it when a button is click. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare bool property in your form, something like this:

```
public Form1
{
   bool TabSelectingAllowed {get;set;}
```

when user clicks on button, change value

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TabSelectingAllowed = true;
}
```

in you existing code add additional checking for value of that property

```
private void tabControl_Selecting(object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.TabPage == tabPage)
    {
       if (!TabSelectingAllowed)
           e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```